# Update DeveloperMetadata of google sheet using google sheet api

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client). I can create and access the DeveloperMetadata of the spreadsheet. But cannot update the DeveloperMetadata. Please see the below code for a better understanding.

```
<?php
class GoogleSheetHelper {
    function update_dev_meta() {
    $dev_meta = new DeveloperMetadata();
    $dev_meta->setVisibility( 'DOCUMENT' );
    $dev_meta->setMetadataKey( 'new_meta_key' );
    $dev_meta->setMetadataValue( 'new_meta_value_updated' );

    $update_req = new UpdateDeveloperMetadataRequest();
    $update_req->setDeveloperMetadata( $dev_meta );
    $update_req->setFields( '*' );

    $request = new Request();
    $request->setUpdateDeveloperMetadata( $update_req );

    $batch_update = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
    $batch_update->setRequests( [ $request ] );

    $client  = $this->get_client();
    $service = new Sheets( $client );

    try {
        return $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate( $spreadsheet_id, $batch_update );
    } catch ( Exception $ex ) {
        var_dump( $ex->getErrors() );

        return false;
    }
}

private function get_client( $scopes = [] ) {
    $credential = 'location/of/credential.json';

    if ( empty( $credential ) ) {
        return null;
    }

    $default_scopes = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    ];

    return new Client(
        [
            'credentials' => $credential,
            'scopes'      => $default_scopes,
        ]
    );
}
}
```

Feel free to notify me of any queries. Sorry for my poor English skill.

Answer (score 1):

Checking your code and the documentation it seems that you are missing to specify a [`Data Filter`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DataFilter) and a [`DeveloperMetadata Object`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.developerMetadata) including a field mask that declares fields to be updated. Please check the documentation on [how to update the developer metadata](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/metadata#update_metadata) to corroborate you are doing it properly.

Here is the example shown that updates the developer metadata, it's not that far from what you currently have:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateDeveloperMetadata": {
        "dataFilters": [
          {
            "developerMetadataLookup": {
              "metadataId": metadataId
            }
          }
        ],
        "developerMetadata": {
          "location": {
            "sheetId": sheetId
          },
          "metadataKey": "SalesUpdated"
        },
        "fields": "location,metadataKey"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```